# How to write if condition in while loop to terminate it

Tags: c

How to write if condition in while loop?

My first approach is

```
#define if(x) 0

main{

       while(if(1))   /// is it right 
          {
          }  
}
```

Without macro I am getting error like:
expected expression before 'if'

Comment: `while` already works like an if - every iteration it checks the value between the Brackets `( )`. If the value is 0 the loop stops

Comment: `#define if(x) 0` - This is a very stupid idea using macros with the same name as keywords.

Comment: It's time to start reading your C textbook.

Comment: I am surprised no one mentioned `break`...

Comment: I know the basic of while loop

Is anyone have idea ?? putting of condition which directly break my loop??

while(if <condition>);

looking for perfect condition <condition>

Answer (score 2):

```
While ( x == true ) {

   //some code

   if ([insert exist condition here]){
       x = false;
   );

}
```

Pay attention that the exist condition can be satisfied somehow, or ur code will run forever

Comment: `x == true` is really bad form, in my opinion (since that expression returns the same type as `x`, assuming it's a `bool`).

Comment: @unwind I was surprised to find this way of checking booleans to be the recommended one in a local coding standard on my workplace...

Comment: I am in no way stating that this is the ultimate way to go. I am answering a specific question.

Comment: @ElioKhattar Yeah, some people think "it's clearer", which I just fail to understand. Every literal you type is another chance to mess up and write the wrong one, plus opens the door for Yoda-style and other scary things. In my world there's just no contest between `if(x)` and `if(!x)` and `if(x == true)` and `if(x == false)`. The former reads like "if x" and "if not x", the latter ... don't.

Comment: @Elio Khattar

I am asking

while(if(condition))    //  what would be the condition that breaks this 
                                 //while loop

Nothing like later condition changed inside while loop, as you suggested...That is  straight forward...

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding something.

The "thing" that goes inside the parentheses in a `while` statement *is* the condition, that's how you read it:

```
while(CONDITION)
{
}
```

evaluates the (braced) expression until the CONDITION is false. If it's false from the beginning, the expression is never evaluated.

There's no need for an `if`, and your macro just makes it all very very very confusing. *Never* clobber keywords with macros.

This is very basic C syntax.

If, on the other hand, you want to stop the `while` before the CONDITION becomes false, you can use `break` inside the expression:

```
while(CONDITION)
{
  ...
  if(SOME_OTHER_CONDITION)
   break;
  ...
}
```